# Form Recognizer Api | Fix from 11.05.2020 | Client Prases results with null fields

Tags: .net, azure, api, nuget, azure-form-recognizer

Is there an updated NuGet package for the latest Fix from the 11-05-2020 available? We basically need the latest fixes from the Azure.AI.Formrecognizer 1.0.0-preview.3 version.

Regarding this Post:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/commit/904cfe1cb490047ffb622843afb385b4dd1dff12#diff-16e8103b54629d7b864160cc0edd0bde

Since I very much need this NuGet package in order to continue my development, I would be more than happy if I could install one as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Please find here the latest SDKs releases docs, these SDKs support the Form Recognizer v2.0 release:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/client-library?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp